# Aptana - Mobile Phone Emulators

Tags: aptana

I'm new to the Aptana Studio 3 development environment.  I have created some .html pages (and want to add jQuery Mobile at some point) and would like to see how they would look on a mobile phone, such as an iPhone or Android device.

When I click on the RUN button I have the choices of (A) Firefox - Internal Server or (B) Internet Explorer - Internal Server.  This does bring up a view...but it really doesn't show how the code will look on a mobile phone.

Is there a way so that I can click on RUN (or whatever) and have the view come up as though it was on a mobile phone?

Not sure if I need to install some emulator or plug-in or configure my environment?

I've heard that something called "Titanium Studo" might be better?

Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Studo is an IDE for developping mobile application such as Android & iPhone using javascript, and we test our application  into Android & iphone simulator.

There is also a mobile web project that allows you to create mobile web application using HTML5 (like m.facebook.com), but i didn't see any web simulator for mobile in Titanium Studo.

For ipad, i use this website to test: ipadpeek.com

Answer (score 0):

Test ripple emulator in Chrome which is an extension